# Check if page returns true or false

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to verify a Minecraft username is paid or not.

By typing in the username at the end of the URL, it returns true or false.

```
$input = 'Notch';

  function checkPlayer($player) {
    $mcURL = 'http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=';
    $auth = file_get_contents($mcURL . $player);
    if ($auth === true) {
      echo $player. ' is valid';
    } else {
      echo $player. ' is not valid';
    }
  }

  checkPlayer($input);
```

But it doesn't return true. By going to the page http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=Notch, it does return true. How do I properly check? I think `file_get_contents` is the wrong function to use for this matter. I'm not sure though.

Comment: can you provide a valid user ID for us to test it?

Comment: Notch is a valid user ID....... It returns true on the page, but not for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line :

```
if ($auth === true) {
```

with

```
if (trim($auth) == "true") {
```

Comment: Okay, thank you! Using print_r, I know it works. it returns true or false now on the page. Something is wrong with my if statement though. It echos out the true statement, even if its false......

Comment: Oh, I got it! Thank you! true/false is a string on the page. I see now.